# Java Android - Either there is not enough memory for the backgroud task or there's a problem with the GC

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, memory

My android app is supposed to read about 25kb from a InputStream which is wrapped in a BufferedReader. This happens in a background Thread that communicates via a Handler. But when starting to read the Thread seems to be blocked and a debug message shows up:

`09-29 22:56:27.837 13625-13640/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 519353(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 77% free, 2MB/10MB, paused 797us total 109.196ms`

I don't know how to handle or bypass it and I wasn't able to find something useful on the internet. I would be very thankful for any tipps or solutions.

Here is the code and the log:

Method:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    if (request == null)
        return;
    int responseHash = 0;
    int returnCode = 0;
    String timestamp = "0";
    int responseType = 0;
    Object returnObject = "";

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ((networkInfo == null) || (!networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
        returnCode = 1;
    } else {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            pw.println("get " + request);
            pw.flush();
            String responseString = "";
            Log.d("EpOs", "1");
            while (!br.ready());
            int i = 0;
            while (br.ready()){
                Log.d("EpOs", "ln"+i++);
                char c;
                c = (char)br.read();
                if (c != 0)
                    responseString += Character.toString(c);
            }
            Log.d("EpOs", "1.5");
            System.out.println(responseString);
            timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("E HH:mm").format(new Date());
            switch (request) {
                case "service/vertretungsplan": {
                    try {
                        responseType = 101;
                        SubstituteDay sd = SubstitutePlanGetter.getSubstitutions(responseString)[0];
                    } catch (URISyntaxException | ImplicitLoginException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        returnCode = 21;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    returnCode = 2;
                }
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            returnCode = 3;
        }
        Log.d("EpOs", "2");
        Integer rc = returnCode;
        Object[] objects = new Object[3];
        objects[0] = rc;
        objects[1] = timestamp;
        objects[2] = returnObject;
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(responseType, objects);
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }
```

Logcat:

```
09-29 23:12:42.866 21779-21779/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-29 23:12:43.278 21779-21779/de.jzbor.epos I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-29 23:12:43.476 21779-21779/de.jzbor.epos W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-29 23:12:43.533 21779-21779/de.jzbor.epos D/EpOs: Test
09-29 23:12:44.150 21779-21779/de.jzbor.epos I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = false
09-29 23:12:44.153 21779-21804/de.jzbor.epos D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-29 23:12:44.215 21779-21804/de.jzbor.epos I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
    Build Date: 04/28/15 Tue
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: 
    Local Patches: 
    Reconstruct Branch: 
09-29 23:12:44.217 21779-21804/de.jzbor.epos I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-29 23:12:44.231 21779-21804/de.jzbor.epos D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-29 23:12:44.396 21779-21779/de.jzbor.epos W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
09-29 23:12:44.501 21779-21779/de.jzbor.epos I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@69cc367 time:42529086
09-29 23:12:48.039 21779-21829/de.jzbor.epos D/EpOs: 1
09-29 23:12:56.169 21779-21794/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 569396(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 77% free, 2MB/10MB, paused 768us total 112.713ms
09-29 23:13:03.718 21779-21794/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 523840(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 83% free, 2MB/14MB, paused 656us total 116.436ms
09-29 23:13:14.916 21779-21794/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 784615(11MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 77% free, 2MB/10MB, paused 489us total 122.385ms
09-29 23:13:29.955 21779-21794/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 521041(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 77% free, 2MB/10MB, paused 727us total 103.527ms
09-29 23:15:34.196 21779-22644/de.jzbor.epos D/EpOs: 1
09-29 23:16:24.117 21779-21794/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 514462(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 76% free, 2MB/10MB, paused 539us total 101.177ms
09-29 23:17:09.050 21779-21794/de.jzbor.epos I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 514702(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 75% free, 2MB/10MB, paused 607us total 106.134ms
```

Comment: That means that GC (Garbage Collector) is freeing memory but either you are have too many allocations of objects or there is infinite loop or both actually. Are you sure you are using `while` loop correctly? Try like this: 
`StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
 String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    responseString.append(line);
}`

Comment: looking at your logging this loop `while (!br.ready());` is looping continuously, never passing this, hence your own logic is blocking the thread - check your `ServerSocket` is ready to send data.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Although it was a good step to figuring out the problem, but the loop wasnt't the bug itsself but rather a consequence. The problem was server not sending anything **at all**. I'll improve my app to handle this error.